# IE 9 CSS gradient with image in background not working

Tags: internet-explorer, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I'm using this code it's working fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE9. and according to this page [Multiple background](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) and [background-size](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) is supported in IE9

```
span.select {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    text-indent: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: url(../img/color-arrow.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#a9a9a9 100%);
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 1;
    border: #dadada 1px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-position: 100% center;
    background-size: 1.5em 0.6em, 100% 100%;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap }
```

I'm using Multiple background and Background Resize in it

Answer (score 2):

[IE9 Doesn't support gradients. IE10 supports them unprefixed](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradients). IE9 did implement SVG however.

I'd recommend using [colorzilla's gradient editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). To use SVG as a fallback, just check their "IE9 Support" checkbox.

If you really need gradients in IE8 (which you shouldn't, cause they should be used for progressive enhancement only) you can use [IE's proprietary filter property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but be careful, cause it's very buggy.

Comment: I've added `-ms-` but it's still not showing because Multiple background is not working

Comment: -ms- prefix is for IE10 support, as far as I know. There are some proprietary filters, which are supported by IE9 and some older versions - you might want to look into those.

Comment: @Dmitriy IE10 supports gradients unprefixed. No need for the `-ms-` prefix. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

IE9 supports multiple background **images**, but not a mix of multiple background elements. Your issue is the image AND the gradient.

In addition -ms- doesn't do anything for CSS compatibility on any property.

Comment: The term "background element" is wrong. A linear gradient is merely a *generated* background image.

Comment: @PointedEars - I'd have to disagree. "element" refers to any number of items, gradients, images, colors....

Comment: I suggest "values" instead, because "elements" is already taken in markup languages, which CSS is formatting.